# If there are multiple errors in 1 question, should it be marked as duplicate for an additional error found but not specified?

Tags: discussion

My [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148438/how-to-modify-a-map-annotation) was marked as duplicate for an additional error found in my code. The issue I'm trying to resolve in my question is regarding a specific runtime error but [a member](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23528/daniel-a-white) closed it, marking it as duplicate for a logic error that was additionally found in my code.

I was under the impression that the scope of my post would stay within the scope of my question and not stray to other issues in my code, especially when unrelated.

Comment: That's why you should post a MCVE.

Comment: @Braiam That doesn't answer my question either. However, I did post ~25 lines to make it clear as to what I was doing. So it should be marked as duplicate if it's not a MCVE?

Comment: If that error is not pivotal to the question, edit the question to correct the error, making sure to leave the specific error you want fixed in the question, then vote to reopen to put it into the reopen queue

Answer (score 2):

Code in the post has at least one obvious error - so since what you've posted in the question should be considered MCVE it is perfectly fine to close as duplicate of any related problems in MCVE.

There is really nothing wrong with having post closed as duplicate  - if the solution in suggested/selected duplicate does not address your question - simply edit your question to clarify and possibly vote to re-open (not sure if author can reopen).

---

Note that I personally disagree with the way question closed - should be closed as "no MCVE" and possibly downvted due to code being unrelated to reported error. You can check the post and see that `'data[i].img_url'` not present at all in the code.

Comment: I can definitely agree with the second half of your post, for the first half...I am unsure. I know I'd feel more than a little miffed if the mcve I posted also had an inadvertent null reference problem (as a result of making the mcve not present in the actual codebase, say...due to omitting an irreverent portion of code) get closed as a duplicate of "what is a null reference error?"

Comment: @Draco18s MCVE is not "grab some random lines from my code and remove some to fit on a screen" - instead it should be result of explicit effort to demonstrate the problem - complete and verifiable are important parts. So if one claims (implicitly or explicitly) that post has MCVE and that code throws NRE there are essentially two options - call OP lair/lazy/... (not nice) or close as duplicate of "fix NRE" (so OP can learn and possibly edit post with improved MCVE).

Comment: I've posted code in questions before that have a comment along the lines of "assume this object isn't null" because it's being passed in from somewhere else. If I were to leave that comment out, now my mcve has a NPE buried in it. I work in Unity a lot and [Unity programs cannot be 100% complete when posted to SO](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/141848/why-does-collision-only-work-when-keys-are-being-pressed#comment251902_141848). In this specific case, the mcve was bad, sure. But you can't generalize like that.